# Replacement for CSS3 function repeating-linear-gradient() in .NET (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Is there any replacement (analogue) for CSS3 function **repeating-linear-gradient()** in .NET (WinForms, not WPF)?
I need to paint repeating "zebra stripes" (e.g. red, blue, green, red, blue, green, ...) at an angle 45 degrees.

**UPD:**
Following Jimi's advice I managed to solve the problem only partially:

```
private void DrawRepeatingStripes(int degree, int stripeWidth, Color[] colors, Rectangle rect, Graphics graphics)
{
    using (var img = new Bitmap(colors.Length * stripeWidth, rect.Height))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
            {
                // TODO: cache SolidBrush
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(colors[i]), stripeWidth * i, 0, stripeWidth, rect.Height);
            }
        }
        using (var tb = new TextureBrush(img, WrapMode.Tile))
        {
            using (var myMatrix = new Matrix())
            {
                myMatrix.Rotate(degree);
                graphics.Transform = myMatrix;
                graphics.FillRectangle(tb, rect);
                graphics.ResetTransform();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (in some form's code):

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    DrawRepeatingStripes(45, 10, new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green }, e.ClipRectangle, e.Graphics);
}
```

The problem is that rotation is... well, a *rotation*, so part of rect is filled with stripes and part **is empty**. Have no idea how to solve it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example about using a [TextureBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.texturebrush) to fill the surface of a Control used as canvas.
The `LinearRepeatingGradient` class exposes a bindable `ColorBands` Property (of Type `BindingList<ColorBand>`) that allows to add or remove `ColorBand` objects, a record that defines the Color and size of each band you want to generate.

The `RotationAngle` Property specifies the rotation to apply to the rendering.

In the `Paint` event of the Control used as canvas, call the `Fill(Graphics g)` method, passing the `e.Graphics` object provided by the `PaintEventArgs` argument.
A new Bitmap is generated, based on the content of the `ColorBands` Property.
When the rotation angle cannot be exactly divided by `90`, the canvas' dimensions are inflated by a third of its diagonal (as the maximum distance from the non-rotated rectangle).
The TextureBrush fills this inflated surface, so no blank space is left on the sides of the canvas.

Since this test sample is built with .NET 7, I'm using `record` to store the color bands' settings. You can replace it with a class object without changes to the rest of the code.

```
public record ColorBand(Color Color, int Size) {
    public override string ToString() => $"Color: {Color.Name} Size: {Size}";
}
```

Same as above: [`using` declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) instead of `using` statements

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

public class LinearRepeatingGradient
{
    public LinearRepeatingGradient(float rotation = .0f)
    {
        ColorBands = new BindingList<ColorBand>();
        RotationAngle = rotation;
    }

    public float RotationAngle { get; set; }

    [Bindable(true), ListBindable(BindableSupport.Default)]
    public BindingList<ColorBand> ColorBands { get; }

    public void Fill(Graphics g) => Fill(g, g.ClipBounds);

    public void Fill(Graphics g, Rectangle fillArea) => Fill(g, new RectangleF(fillArea.Location, fillArea.Size));

    protected virtual void Fill(Graphics g, RectangleF display)
    {
        if (ColorBands is null || ColorBands.Count == 0 || g.Clip.IsInfinite(g)) return;

        var canvas = InflateCanvas(display);
        var centerPoint = new PointF(canvas.X + canvas.Width / 2, canvas.Y + canvas.Height / 2);

        using var texture = GetTexture(canvas.Width);
        if (texture is null) return;
        using var brush = new TextureBrush(texture, WrapMode.Tile);
        using var mx = new Matrix();
        mx.RotateAt(RotationAngle, centerPoint);
        g.Transform = mx;
        g.FillRectangle(brush, canvas);
        g.ResetTransform();
    }

    private RectangleF InflateCanvas(RectangleF rect)
    {
        if (RotationAngle % 90.0f == 0) return rect;
        float maxInflate = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(rect.X - rect.Right, 2) +
                                            Math.Pow(rect.Y - rect.Bottom, 2)) / 3.0f;
        var canvas = rect;
        canvas.Inflate(maxInflate, maxInflate);
        return canvas;
    }

    private Bitmap? GetTexture(float width)
    {
        int height = ColorBands!.Sum(c => c.Size);
        if (height <= 0) return null;
        var texture = new Bitmap((int)(width + .5f), height);
        int startPosition = 0;

        using var g = Graphics.FromImage(texture);
        for (int i = 0; i < ColorBands!.Count; i++) {
            var rect = new Rectangle(0, startPosition, texture.Width, ColorBands![i].Size);
            using var brush = new SolidBrush(ColorBands![i].Color);
            g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            startPosition += ColorBands![i].Size;
        }
        return texture;
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: Linear Repeating Gradient]

Since the `ColorBands` property is bindable, you can use data bindings to perform actions, when a `ColorBand` object is added or removed and also bind the `ColorBands` collection to Controls, as shown in the animation:

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form {

    LinearRepeatingGradient gradient = new();

    public SomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        [Your DataGridView].DataSource = gradient.ColorBands;
        gradient.ColorBands.ListChanged += (s, e) => someControl.Invalidate();
    }

    private void someControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) =>
        gradient.Fill(e.Graphics);
```

As a consequence, when you add a new `ColorBand` (or remove it), the internal collection changes and the Control used as canvas is invalidated, showing the new fill:

```
gradient.ColorBands.Add(new ColorBand(Color.Red, 45f));
```

The `RotationAngle` property doesn't use data bindings, so you have to invalidate the canvas *manually* when you change it. You can of course change that and make this property bindable:

```
gradient.RotationAngle = 215f;
someControl.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! The only thing I corrected - I added 2nd argument: public void Fill(Graphics g, RectangleF rect) and pass PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle instead of using g.ClipBounds because the latter is gargantuan.

Comment: `ClipBounds` is ok here, since you're passing the *fresh* Graphics object you get from the PaintEventArgs of a Paint event. But, since it could be ~Infinite, I've added a check on that (and a couple of other changes, safe measures). You of course can pass whatever measure you prefer. It could also be the Control's DisplayRectangle, in case the Control can be scrolled

Comment: However, in DataGridView cell it doesn't work as expected... but maybe I'm doing smth wrong? -

private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    // gradient1 - 45 deg and 2 colors; gradient2 - 135 deg and 2 other colors
    if (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
        gradient1.Fill(e.Graphics, new Color[] { ... }, e.CellBounds);
    else
        gradient2.Fill(e.Graphics, new Color[] { ... }, e.CellBounds);
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
    e.Handled = true;
}

(I use array of colors and fixed band width)

Comment: Seems I managed to repair it: instead of InflateCanvas, Matrix.RotateAt and Graphics.Transform - used simply Brush.RotateTransform. DataGridView cells are filled correctly. The only problem is that scrolling sometimes results in slight texture corruption.